Degree of an isogeny of Abelian schemes in AGII Görtz-Wedhorn.
Let $f : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ be an isogeny of Abelian schemes over a scheme $S$. In Algebraic Geometry II by Görtz-Wedhorn the degree of $f$ (as an isogeny) is defined (in page 670) as the degree of the finite locally free homomorphism $\mathrm{ker} f \rightarrow S$. The degree of a finite locally free morphism of schemes $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is defined in the first volume of the series (page 333) as a the locally constant function $ y \mapsto \dim_{k(y)} (f_* \mathcal{O}_{X})_y \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}} k(y)$ on Y.
I would like to know how this notion of degree behaves when $S=\mathrm{Spec} \ k$ for a field $k$, i.e., when $f : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ is an isogeny between Abelian varieties. In this case most of the textbooks treating Abelian varieties define the degree of such an isogeny $f$ to be directly the degree of $f$ (as a finite locally free morphism), which is $[k(\mathcal{A}):k(\mathcal{B})]$ in this case (this is explained in page 333 of AGI). However, I can not get that the degree of $f$ (as an isogeny) is $[k(\mathcal{A}):k(\mathcal{B})]$ following the definition of AGII Görtz-Wedhorn. Are this two notions equal?
On the other hand, why would someone want to define the degree of $f$ as an isogeny to be the degree of $\mathrm{ker} f \rightarrow S$ and not just the degree of $f : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ directly? The isogeny $f$ is also finite locally free (Corollary 27.177), so this is well defined.

You're just asking why the degree of $f$ and $\ker(f)\to S$ is the same? Note that $A\to B$ is faithfully flat, and $A\times_B A\simeq A\times_S \ker(f)$ as an $A$-scheme. From this you can see the claim you want, right?

Thanks for the comment. I don't know if the degree of $f$ and $\ker (f) \rightarrow S$ are the same, but if they are, that would answer my question. Please, could you write a full answer? I don't understand your explanation.

Hey, I've changed my comment to an answer.

As mentioned above, it suffices to show that the degrees of the finite locally free morphisms
$$f\colon A\to B,\qquad \ker(f)\to S$$
are the same. That said, let us observe that there is a natural isomorphism of $A$-schemes
$$A\times_B A\xrightarrow{\sim} \ker(f)\times_S A,\qquad (a_1,a_2)\mapsto (a_1a_2^{-1},a_2).$$
Let us write this common $A$-scheme as $X$. Then, $X\to A$ is finite locally free of degree $\deg(f)$ as it is the base change of $f$ along $A\to B$. On the other hand, as it is isomorphic to $\ker(f)\times_S A\to A$, and so the base change of $\ker(f)\to S$ along $A\to S$, we see that $X\to A$ also has degree $\deg(\ker(f)\to S)$. Thus,
$$\deg(f)=\deg\left(\ker(f)\to S\right),$$
as desired.

Thanks for writing it as an answer. Is it a general fact that "degree is preserved by base change"? It feels strange to me because the degree of a morphism and the degree of the base change are defined as locally constant functions on different domains.

@Andarrkor You're not wrong, but this is a minor technical point that can be erased by observing that $\pi_0(\mathcal{B})\to \pi_0(S)$ is a bijection. If it makes you happy, then you can assume that $S$ is connected. In any case, one way to think about the degree $d$ of a finite locally free morphism $f\colon X\to Y$ is that $f_\ast\mathcal{O}_X$ is a vector bundle of degree $d$. It is clear this is preserved by base change.

@Andarrkor If it makes you happy, then if $f\colon X\to Y$ is finite locally free with degree function $\mathrm{deg}(f)\colon |Y|\to \mathbb{Z}$ then for any map $g\colon Y'\to Y$ the map $f'=f\times 1\colon X\times_Y Y'\to Y'$ is finite locally free of degree $\mathrm{deg}(f')=\mathrm{deg}(f)\circ g$. This can also be used to resolve your question.

This solves my question and does make me happy. Thank you very much Alex :)

@Andarrkor No worries -- glad it helped!
